# Combining linerange, firstnumber and consecutivenumbers leads to non-consecutive numbers

Tags: listings, line-numbering

If I use linerange, firstnumber and consecutivenumbers with line markers it results in non-consecutive line numbers. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{filecontents}{file.java}
{a}
Hello world 1
{end}
{b}
Hello world 2
{end}
\end{filecontents} 
\begin{document} 
\lstset{
  numbers=left,
  rangeprefix=\{,
  rangesuffix=\},
  firstnumber=0,
  consecutivenumbers=true
}
\lstinputlisting[
  linerange={a-end,b-end}
]{file.java}
\end{document}
```

Results in:

```
0 {a}
1 Hello  world 1
2 {end}
0 {b}
1 Hello  world 2
2 {end}
```

I would expect:

```
0 {a}
1 Hello  world 1
2 {end}
3 {b}
4 Hello  world 2
5 {end}
```

I have listings 1.8d from CTAN. Is this a bug, or am I misusing the package? If I want to report this bug, do I just... Email the maintainer?

Comment: Goeiemiddag, the documentation states (page 56) "Send a bug report to the address on the first page of this documentation and include the minimal file together with the created .log-file."

Comment: Of course, I should've searched the docs for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a list of markers as `linerange` multiple listings are constructed, and for each new listing `firstnumber=0` is executed. According to the documentation `consecutivenumbers` can  be  used  on  individual  listings  only, so the bug would be that a list of ranges is not considered as an 'individual listing'.

As a workaround you can disable the macro `\lst@InitLstNumber` that is used with ranges to initialise the number.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{filecontents}{exfile.java}
{a}
Hello world 1
{end}
extra line
{b}
Hello world 2
{end}
\end{filecontents} 
\begin{document} 
\lstset{
  numbers=left,
  rangeprefix=\{,
  rangesuffix=\},
  firstnumber=0,
  %consecutivenumbers=true
}
\makeatletter
\def\lst@InitLstNumber{\relax}
\makeatother

\lstinputlisting[
  linerange={a-end,b-end}
]{exfile.java}
\end{document}
```

Note that I added an extra line to the example file to check that the numbering is indeed consecutive.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for, as I'm on a tight deadline. If you don't mind me asking, do you think I should report this as a bug/clarification of the docs, or is this "technically speaking" expected behavior of listings?